# Is SMPS a non-isolated power supply?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I came across an online tutorial which has the following category:

[image]

As you see SMPS is categorized as a non-isolated power supply.
Or am I interpreting the tree wrong?

But isnt an SMPS isolated through a transformer and opto-coupling(for the feedback)?

Comment: It can be either.

Comment: "As you see SMPS is categorized as a non-isolated power supply." No, what I see is that non-isolated DC power supplies can be divided into linear and switch-mode.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You are right I definitely got it wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's only a part of the power supply taxonomy tree.  The other parts of the taxonomy are probably in a further section of your tutorials.  A bigger picture might look like this:

[image]

The blue dotted line shows the sub-section of the tree posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nick's chart, it is worth noting that the isolated converters perform similar functions as the non-isolated ones. For example: the flyback works like a buck-boost, the forward / push-pull / full-bridge work like buck converters.

The mechanics are a little different though.